# Issue with adding image to SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I have successfully added a batch of images stored in binary from a database in Report Builder YAYE!!! Ok hold the applause because I need to have the image display on the company's web server and for some reason it's only showing in Report Builder. Does anyone have a theory as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an [Execution Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181156.aspx) with minimum permissions to the database in order to allow the report server read images from external sources

[image]

Comment: What if the images pull from the same database that the table logic is in? Or are you saying that is the same thing as external images?

Comment: Same thing because images are stored on another repository (database) and you want to access from the company's web server to report server it needs a way to authenticate in order to retrieve values, you can also take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141825/unattended-execution-account-in-ssrs)

Comment: Ok I will speak to the network admins then thanks for the input.